Get Android application crash dump
Currently i'm testing video rendering on surface which causing app crash or ANR sometimes. During analysis i've seen a line at the end of logs which is Requested dump for pid 25612. I want to know if this line means save crash dump in some location in files then where(specifically in macos).

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@MarioMateaș you can find this line in logs by generating ANR anyhow.
